# Android custom imageview with webview-like scaling

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

i think this question has been asked quite often, but I couldn`t find an appropriate solution for my implementation. I built an custom imageview with an **onScaleListener** and an **onGestureListener** that scales and pans the containing image. The scaling is done with a matrix scaling. The function looks like that:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
            scaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(initScale, Math.min(scaleFactor, initScale + 3.0f));
            matrix = getImageMatrix();
            matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
            matrix.getValues(values);
            matrix.postTranslate(-values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + Math.max(0, centerX - centerImageX),
                    -values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + Math.max(0, centerY - centerImageY));
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

postTranslate() is needed to center the image if needed. To finish this I need to scroll to (scrollTo(x,y)) the position where the focus of the scaling gesture stays in the same position on the screen. At the end it should look like scaling in a webview.
 Can anybody help me with this?
When I use:
        float scrollPosX = ((scrollwidth) * ((getScrollX() + touchX) / imagewidth));
        float scrollPosY = ((scrollheight) * ((getScrollY() + touchY) / imageheight));
it will work for the first scaling, but when scaling in a scaled image it will scroll to the relative position. I think it is all related to the fact that I only get the touch position with **getScrollX()** and **getScrollY()** [it`s difficult to explain]

Comment: If you're willing to use a library to do this, my custom image view class supports pinch to zoom, and moves the image as you pinch to keep the center point of the pinch at the start aligned with the center point as you move your fingers together/apart. Not a great explanation but I think it's what you mean :-) https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: Nice code, thank you very much. But I prefer to finish my code because I need to load images from web, it is almost finished and i spend a lot of time with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found a solution that works for me. In my case I have to use the scaling step instead of the scaling factor.

```
                scrollTo((int) (getScrollX() - x + (scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor() * x) ),
                         (int) (getScrollY() - y + (scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor() * y) ));
```

with x and y as the touch position on the scaled image.